# C++ Static Friend Method Example (Need Clarification)

Tags: c++, implementation, static-methods, friend

This is a how C++ works question.

I've been looking into the `friend` modifier and found an example of a `static friend` method [here.](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/539425-static-friend-function)

But now I'm having trouble understanding **why** certain things were done to make it work.

I'm also curious of what ***practical*** application this could be used for? When would you **want** to use `static friend`? Should this be avoided?

Here's the code with comments added to point out parts I'm confused about.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A; //1. why declare class A here and define it below?

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();

    static void SetAiPrivate(int value); //Makes SetAiPrivate static
    static A *pa; //static instance of class A for class B's static 
                  //methods to use
};

class A
{
friend void B::SetAiPrivate(int); //Gives Class B's SetAiPrivate method access
                                  //to A's private variables

public:
    A(){iPrivate = 0;}
    ~A(){}
    void PrintData(){ std::cout << "iPrivate = "<< iPrivate<<"\n";}

private:
    int iPrivate;
};


A *B::pa;//2. Why is this needed? 
         //   If commented out it causes an external linking error.

B::B()
{
    pa = new A;
}     
B::~B()
{
    delete pa;
}

void B::SetAiPrivate(int value)
{
    pa->iPrivate = value;
}

int main()
{
    B b; //3. Is this necessary? Doesn't C++ automatically initiate static
         //   member variables when a class is referenced

    B::SetAiPrivate(7);
    B::pa->PrintData();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the code first:

> class A; //1. why declare class A here and define it below?

That's a forward declaration. `B` has a member of type `A*`, so `A` must be declared beforehand.

> A *B::pa;//2. Why is this needed?

Static data members are only declared inside the class definition. That's the definition and it's required by the standard to be present in a single translation unit.

> B b; //3. Is this necessary? Doesn't C++ automatically initiate static
>            //   member variables when a class is referenced

Not necessary. Unless of course the `static` methods in `B` depend on the run of the constructor. And if they do, it's a bad design.

Onto the `friend` question. Usually, having friends breaks encapsulation, be them only members or a whole class. This is no different. It just tells the compiler that `A::iPrivate` is directly accessible from `B::SetAiPrivate`.

This looks wrong to me, as you'd probably want to be able to set `A`'s member directly from `A`, not from `B`.

Comment: So would you advise against using the `friend` key word? When is it appropriate to use `friend`? I've read some talk about operators being a good place for `friend` or `static`. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Dan definitely against because it breaks encapsulation. A valid reason for use is testing purposes, when a test class can check privates. But that doesn't influence the design of the actual program.

Comment: [Do friends violate encapsulation?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/friends-and-encap.html): "*No! If they're used properly, they enhance encapsulation.*"

Answer (score 1):

> 1 why declare class A here and define it below?

You need to forward declare A if it is defined after class B as class B contains a pointer to an instance of A. Had you defined class A before class B this would not be needed

> 2 Why is this needed?

Static members must be initialised somewhere outside of the class definition

> 3 Is this necessary? Doesn't C++ automatically initiate static member variables when a class is referenced

AFAIK know this would not be needed for the very reasons that you mention